# On click add remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys I am struggling to add/remove **active** class of twitter bootstrap indicator when user clicks on indicator or slider arrow. Can anyone help me with this one:

here is code:

```
$('.carousel-indicators  li, .carousel-control').on("click",function(){ 
$('.carousel-indicators li.active').removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

**[Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuxfxz1w/)**

**[Here is working jsFiddle without swipe feature.](http://jsfiddle.net/nuxfxz1w/2/)**

Curently it works with numbers but when user clicks on any arrows or swipes it removes class only without adding to indicator new active class.

Searching for example!!

Comment: Thats because the active class gets applied to the arrows when you click on them and not the numbers...?

Comment: I think [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) is what you are looking for

Comment: you need to have a different handler for the arrow buttons

Comment: Can anyone write an example?

Comment: @hitesh it does not work?

Comment: can you simplify your fiddle it is really complex

Comment: Please check it now. I have upaded jsFiddle.

Comment: are you saying "http://jsfiddle.net/nuxfxz1w/" this is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63579/discussion-between-ninja-kornjaca-and-hitesh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are a working example http://jsfiddle.net/nuxfxz1w/10/

You just need to bind the slid event from bootstrap carousel

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function () {

    $('.carousel-indicators .active').removeClass('active');
    var activeIndex = $('#myCarousel .item.active').index();
    $('.carousel-indicators li:eq(' + activeIndex + ')').addClass('active');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you refer to this inside click handler, and thus setting active class to arrow and not number.

You can do another click handler for clicking the arrows, something like this:

```
$('.carousel-control').click( function(){
    var $next;
    if( this.dataset.slide === "prev"){
        $next = $('.carousel-indicators li.active').prev();
        if( $next[0] === undefined) $next = $('.carousel-indicators li').last();     
    } else {
        $next = $('.carousel-indicators li.active').next();
        if( $next[0] === undefined) $next = $('.carousel-indicators li').first();           
    }

     $('.carousel-indicators li.active').removeClass("active");
    $next.addClass("active");

});
```

I've updated your fiddle, check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuxfxz1w/11/)